# how to use classes in python because it keeps throwing up errors for me

Tags: python, class

```
class PlayerCharacter:
    def _init_ (self, name):
        self.name = name
    def run (self):
        print('run')
player1 = PlayerCharacter('Obiora')

print(player1.name)
```

This code throws:

```
TypeError: PlayerCharacter() takes no arguments
```

Comment: `"_init_" != "__init__"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the init function a dunder like __init__ for instantiating the class object.

```
class PlayerCharacter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print('run')

player1 = PlayerCharacter('Obiora')
```

This code will work.